# iPhone safari and JSONLoader

Tags: iphone, safari, three.js

I just want to make a web3D project in iPhone. But , When I add Line 94's code to do a test , safari comes out to be "javascript error INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." from safari's debug console.
It works in PC's chrome browser well ,but it also has a error "Failed to load resource http://cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js"

```
92 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
93 var geo = function geometery(geom){}; 
94 loader.load("image/robot.js", geo);
```

can you just give me some advice? I used the canvasRenderer

Comment: It seems to have something to do with where you are loading the "http://cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js", Not the code you posted.
You may also want to take a look at the copyright statement in the vglink.js file

Comment: Oh,yes.You are right . I have solved the problem of "cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js". But the problem in safari is still unsolved.